# Best way to compare just the year and month portion of a date in MySQL? Is it safe to do it as strings?

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to compare just the year and month portion of a date?

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m") <= "2015-12"
```

Is it safe to do it as strings, assuming the date formats are sortable?

Or would it be better to cast them as integers first?

```
CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y%m"), UNSIGNED INTEGER) <= 201512
```

EDIT: This also works:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m") BETWEEN '2014-06' AND '2015-12'
```

EDIT 2: Another example of use case would be returning all rows where the date is in any one of several YEAR-MONTH strings.  For example, this also works:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m") IN ('2014-06', '2014-09', '2014-12', '2015-03')
```

Comment: Have you tried simply comparing the `date` against `2015-12` and checking what you get (without any conversion and formatting)?

Comment: If you've found an answer yourself (e.g. the `BETWEEN` operator) feel free to post it, and mark it accepted. By the way, why would you format a date just to check its value? Just do this: `date BETWEEN '2014-06-01 AND '2015-12-31'`

Comment: @N.B. That does work, but I'm not sure I like from a readability standpoint because of the different formats you're comparing. I'm assuming MySQL casts the date as a string first before the comparison.

Comment: @miken32 Those are just examples to show you what I'm doing. The dates could be one or several different YEAR-MONTH strings.

Comment: Ok, but you're adding a lot of overhead by doing formatting on them, and losing any potential benefits of indices on the column.

Comment: @miken32 Then perhaps the best way would be to store it in a separate integer column as 201512 and using just integer values when comparing.

Comment: MySQL casts string input you give it into integers when it compares against date types. You just need to supply correctly formatted date for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. MySQL provides builtin functions to extract year, month, day, etc. Use them. Don't roll your own in any way.

Comment: Such as..? And why is it wrong to compare a date represented as an integer?  Are UNIX timestamps not allowed either (tongue in cheek)?

Comment: Such as [these](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). 12 seconds in Google. It is pointless to write any code that the vendor has already written for you. For one thing it saves you having to ask questions like this. I have no idea what your crack about Unix timestamps is supposed to mean.

Comment: I mean it's perfectly fine to compare dates as integers.  And I know all about the MySQL reference documentation.  It's very useful, I use it all the time.  But it doesn't show anything that's specific to my question.

Comment: Your question is about which is safest, and the answer is that the MySQL date-time functions are safest. They already exist, are tested, etc. No two ways about it.

Comment: So let's say I want to compare a year column to a year string.  Should I first convert that to DATETIME, then EXTRACT the YEAR portion, and then compare?  Or should I just write a FORTRAN program for that?

Comment: Kindly stop talking nonsense, and don't put words into my mouth. I did not use the words you have attributed to me in quotation marks. If you think all your code is OK why are you asking the question?

Comment: Bottom line here is that you actually don't have to do anything. If you stored the date as `timestamp`, MySQL stores it as integer already (much like all date based storage). Therefore, if you compare a `date_column` against `2015-12` - in order to perform such comparison, MySQL will coerce everything to integers behind the scenes and do the job for you. All you are left with is writing normal, understandable and simple SQL, avoiding any possible problems or misunderstandings that might occur if you try converting stuff from one type to another.

Comment: I'm asking about a different or better way.  Your answer and follow-up comments seem to be intentionally unhelpful.  There are so many cases where dates are represented as strings or integers in programming, even in MySQL. For example, the timestamps or `YEARWEEK() = 201512` both use integers. But you seem to just suggest that ONLY certain MySQL functions can be used, but you won't tell me what you would use. And even though I used the `DATE_FORMAT()` from the docs (which you linked to) you will not say why that is wrong. So you seem to be going out of your way to not be helpful.